# Program to group files or folders based on prefix

Tags: file-management

I'm looking for a program that will let me group folders together in a folder depending on the prefix.

So if I have folders, `A-B-C-1` and `A-B-C-2`, since they both have prefix `A` then they will be placed in a folder.

Is there a program for Windows or OS X that will allow this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in PowerShell **3.0** tool in Windows (8+?). 
Open PowerShell 3.0 and choose a prefix filter, search path, and a destination directory.
Example of a command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path "C:\Users\John\Desktop" -Filter "A-*" | foreach {Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Users\John\Documents\Destination-folder" }
```

## Analysis of the command

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory
```

Gets the directories in the specified location

```
-Recurse
```

Also checks sub-directories' sub-directories'...
You can leave this out if you only need to check directories in one folder.

```
-Path "C:\Users\John\Desktop"
```

Specifies the path you want to search for directories in

```
-Filter "A-*"
```

Only selects directories starting with "A-" (This is your prefix). The * is a wildcard which tells PowerShell not to care about what the rest of the directory name.

```
|
```

The "pipe" character sends the output of the first command (Get-ChildItem) to the next command (for further processing)

```
 foreach { }
```

Classic for-loop that does a specified action on each item (aka each directory from Get-ChildItem)

```
 foreach {Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination "C:\Users\John\Documents\Destination-directory" }
```

Move the item "$_" (a variable that represents each item (directory) Get-ChildItem sends) to the specified destination directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this quite quickly with a simple [python](http://python.org) script - assuming that you have all of the folders in a single location to start with, something like, *(untested)*:

```
import os
import collections

folder = os.path.curdir  # Or somewhere else?
dirlist = [d for d in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, d))]
outmap = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name in dirlist:
    pre = name[:1].upper() # 1 is prefix length & make case independent
    if pre.isalnum() and len(name) > len(pre):  # Skip existing and specials
        outmap[pre].append(name)  # Add to the list for that prefix

for k, dirlist in outmap.iteritems(): 
    newdir = os.path.join(folder, k)  # This could be elsewhere
    for d in dirlist:
        os.renames(os.join(folder, d), os.join(newdir, d))
```

The above should work nicely on OS-X, Linux & Windows but you will need to install python on Windows.  Free, Gratis & Open Source.